# Updating a large number of foreign key references in Django

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I have a companies and employees tables, along with a third employees records table which contains a foreign key to both the companies and employees tables.

The company table has an entry of 'Company A'. Subsequently, 'Company A' splits into two new entries: 'Company A1' and 'Company A2'.

Now in the employees records table, currently a large number employees are associated with 'Company A'.

For each employee associated with 'Company A', I want to create two new entries which associates the employee with both 'Company A1' and 'Company A2'.

What would be the optimal way to accomplish this with Django? Considering that there could be hundreds of thousands or possible millions of rows of employee records that need updating.

Comment: Would you not have to change the company->employee foreign key from one-to-many to many-to-many?

Comment: Yes, that's what I imagine would need to occur.

Comment: So you would need to change the field type to many-to-many, then loop through the records and create new connections for each. If you want some sample code you need to publish your models.py